# echo on button class

Tags: javascript, php, html, multi-step

I'm trying to build a multi step selector which has multiple combinations in every slide. for example hou have btn1, btn2 and btn3. Every button will display other content in the next slide.

It's an inpage multistep slider so I can't use onClick, submit input or something like that.

as you can see in the code below, I'm trying to get an echo on the name or value of the button who has been clicked in the slide before.

```js
var currentSlide = 0,
    $slideContainer = $('.slide-container'),
    $slide = $('.slide'),
    slideCount = $slide.length,
    animationTime = 300;

function setSlideDimensions () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $slideContainer.width(windowWidth * slideCount);
  $slide.width(windowWidth);
}

function generatePagination () {
  var $pagination = $('.pagination');
  for(var i = 0; i < slideCount; i ++){
    var $indicator = $('<div>').addClass('indicator'),
        $progressBarContainer = $('<div>').addClass('progress-bar-container'),
        $progressBar = $('<div>').addClass('progress-bar'),
        indicatorTagText = $slide.eq(i).attr('data-tag'),
        $tag = $('<div>').addClass('tag').text(indicatorTagText);
    $indicator.append($tag);
    $progressBarContainer.append($progressBar);
    $pagination.append($indicator).append($progressBarContainer);
  }
  $pagination.find('.indicator').eq(0).addClass('active');
}

function goToNextSlide () {
  if(currentSlide >= slideCount - 1) return; 
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  currentSlide++;
  $slideContainer.animate({
    left: -(windowWidth * currentSlide)
  });
  setActiveIndicator();
  $('.progress-bar').eq(currentSlide - 1).animate({
    width: '100%'
  }, animationTime);
}

function goToPreviousSlide () {
  if(currentSlide <= 0) return; 
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  currentSlide--;
  $slideContainer.animate({
    left: -(windowWidth * currentSlide)
  }, animationTime);
  setActiveIndicator();
  $('.progress-bar').eq(currentSlide).animate({
    width: '0%'
  }, animationTime);
}

function postitionSlides () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  setSlideDimensions();
  $slideContainer.css({
    left: -(windowWidth * currentSlide)
  }, animationTime);
}

function setActiveIndicator () {
  var $indicator = $('.indicator');
  $indicator.removeClass('active').removeClass('complete');
  $indicator.eq(currentSlide).addClass('active');
  for(var i = 0; i < currentSlide; i++){
    $indicator.eq(i).addClass('complete');
  }
}

setSlideDimensions();
generatePagination();
$(window).resize(postitionSlides);
$('.next').on('click', goToNextSlide);
$('.previous').on('click', goToPreviousSlide);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*, html, body {
  font-family: "TrebuchetMS", trebuchet, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #37B595;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #1A7F75;
}
button.previous {
  background-color: #A2ACAF;
}
button.previous:hover {
  background-color: #5A5F61;
}

.full-width-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.sized-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
}
.slide .sized-container {
  padding: 75px 25px;
}

.button-container {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.button-container button {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.pagination-container {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.pagination {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.indicator {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 4px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}
.indicator .tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: lightgray;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.indicator.active, .indicator.complete {
  border-color: #37B595;
}
.indicator.active .tag, .indicator.complete .tag {
  color: #37B595;
}
.indicator.complete:after {
  content: "✓";
  position: absolute;
  color: #37B595;
  left: 4px;
  top: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  width: 10%;
  height: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.progress-bar-container:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
.progress-bar-container .progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #37B595;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-container full-width-container">
  <div class="sized-container">
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="viewport full-width-container">
  <ul class="slide-container">
    <li class="slide" data-tag="Basic Info">
      <div class="sized-container">
        <h1>Slide1.</h1>
    <input class="next" name="next" type="button" value="next" />
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide" data-tag="Expertise">
      <div class="sized-container">
        <h1>Slide2.</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Can someone please help me out!

Comment: can you provide a working code. I'm not sure php works with the snippet

Comment: Why cant you use onclick or an eventlistener?

Comment: @jonny because onClick is giving it an other url. and the multistep is inpage. so when it reloads or go to another url it will start over

Comment: use button instead of input set your button type=button

Comment: @jonny i've tried, but it won't work